# Unwanted border around image which isn't a CSS border or outline using Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Cards from Bootstrap4 and have replaced the image source with .PNG images. However, it shows unwanted border. It isn't a border or an outline. 
[image: Snapshot]

This is the HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <img class="i-home">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <img class="i-solar">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <img class="i-buy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
      <img class="i-advantage">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css

```
.col-md-3{
    padding:50px;
}

.col-md-3 .card{
    border: 0 none !important;
    background: transparent;
}

.i-home{
    display: block;
    background: transparent url(../img/ihome.png) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    border: none;
    height: 225px;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Update:
Images do not have any border
[image: Home image - .PNG]

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse the border line will come. Why because you haven't added the src link for image tag

`<img class="i-home">` : missed src. Eventhough you have added the image via background, you have to pass the src inside image tag. If not the browser will consider as **Invalid Tag declaration**. So by default the missing image will indicated with border surrounding

**Solution1:**

pass an transparent image in src link `<img class="i-home" src="transparent image link">`

**Solution2:**

Replace the image tag with the span tag `<span class="i-home"></span>`

Answer (score -1):

Simply add the class `border-0` to the card divs to remove the borders from the cards.

The border normally comes with the `card` styling but `border-0` can remove it.

It's recommended to use native Bootstrap classes whenever possible (instead of custom css hacks) because custom hacks tend to limit the usefulness of Bootstrap in general:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card mb-3 border-0">
              <img class="i-home">
              content <br>i-home
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow border-0">
              <img class="i-solar">
              content <br>i-solar
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow border-0">
              <img class="i-buy">
              content <br>i-buy
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow border-0">
              <img class="i-advantage">
              content <br>i-advantage
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you have image tag inside the card class, so by default in bootstrap 4, for `.card` has default styles as `border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);` , just remove that by overriding that css like `border:none;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .i-advantage{
    display: block;
    background: transparent url(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/cinqueterre.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-position-y: center;
    border: none;
    height: 225px;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .card {
    border: none;
}
  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
  <img class="i-advantage">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of **`<img>`** tag use **`<div>`** for pulling an image.

**For an instance**: try **`<div class="i-home">`** in place of  **`<img class="i-home">`**